# Android - Get GPU model from files?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, gpu

I search for methods to get some data from the integrated gpu chipset. I have read about GL10 and SurfaceView but isn't there a way similar to the cpu ones by pulling data from files in the sys-folders?

I don't want to let the phone draw something to get the data and prefer to collect them from files.

Is this possible or is there a need to go the OpenGL-way?

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no other way to get system info from files
These files are protected and you should have root permission to access them.
The best way you can interact with them is using adb shell using Opengl in java